# Android: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.imageView cannot be cast to android.widget.textView

Tags: android, xml, templates, textview, imageview

I can't fix this problem on my listview template: i have the error as in the title of my post, but i won't cast imageview to textview. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mq"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Metri quadri"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/citta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mq"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mq"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Citta"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prezzo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Prezzo"
    android:textColor="#e1e1e1"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/testolungo"
    android:textColor="#e1e1e1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/foto"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="Release"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/stub" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descsplash"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The error for the java code is on line 58 of my file, where i assign the TextView id to TextView mq:

```
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlay, null);
    TextView nome=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.nome);
    TextView mq=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mq); // here's the error (???)
    TextView citta=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.citta);
    TextView prezzo=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.prezzo);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.foto);
    TextView descrizione = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.descsplash);
    nome.setText(data.get(position).getNome());
    mq.setText(data.get(position).getMetriQuadri());
    citta.setText(data.get(position).getCitta());
    prezzo.setText(data.get(position).getPrezzo());
    descrizione.setText(data.get(position).getDescrizione());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position).getForoUrl(), image);
```

And here is the logcat:

> 06-25 16:08:32.497: D/Debug(14642): Prendo Textview MQ
>   06-25 16:08:32.497: D/AndroidRuntime(14642): Shutting down VM
>   06-25 16:08:32.497: W/dalvikvm(14642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a561f8)
>   06-25 16:08:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-25 16:08:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14642): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
>   06-25 16:08:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14642): at com.prova.listview.LazyAdapter.getView(LazyAdapter.java:58)

Does anyone know how i can fix this problem?

Comment: Seems correct. Just try to clean your project.

Comment: can you post the catlog? A clean may be what you need as @SpK recommends

Comment: 06-25 16:08:32.497: D/Debug(14642): Prendo Textview MQ
06-25 16:08:32.497: D/AndroidRuntime(14642): Shutting down VM
06-25 16:08:32.497: W/dalvikvm(14642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a561f8)
06-25 16:08:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 16:08:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14642): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
06-25 16:08:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14642):  at com.prova.listview.LazyAdapter.getView(LazyAdapter.java:58)

Comment: thank you guys! how can i clean the project? i'm new in android programming

Comment: @Release You can edit your post to add information at any time. I have added the logcat to your post for you.

Comment: Project > Clean... Select your project and click OK.

Comment: @assylias i'm sorry, now i know it. By the way i solved my problem deleting my R file. Thank you

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Eclipse tends to mess up your resources every now and then.
This leads to some odd behavior such as strings and images being swapped all over your app, and more commonly classCastException(s), which happen when Eclipse switches your Views' ids around.

A few solutions to that problem:

Clean your project.

Modify an xml layout file and save.

Delete your R file. (Don't worry it will be automatically generated again).

Basically anything that makes your project rebuild and re-generate the R file.

Answer (score 4):

Just clean up your project and everything will be fine.

Comment: it didn't help me, I had to change id of the view and recompile

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I was getting error:

`TextView : android:id="@+id/add_expected_seekbarvalue"`

`SeekBar : android:id="@+id/add_expected_seekbar"`

As a fix, I renamed the `id` for `TextView` as

`TextView : android:id="@+id/add_expected_valueseekbar"`

**Even clean up and other techniques didn't work but finally renaming the id worked like a charm.**

Answer (score 1):

Some times this problem shows because we have created ImageView But Cast with Image Button as like this

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_thumb"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        />

  holder.imageView = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumb);
```

we have declared Imageview but cast to ImageButton, for this reason also have face this problem.

Answer (score 1):

for **Visual Studio Xamarin.Android Development**

Like mentioned by many, **Cleaning** the project did the trick for me on Visual Studio
For my Xamarin.Forms app, it happened after pulling in changes with new library reference.

Clean your project.

Basically anything that makes your project rebuild and re-generate the Rosource.Designer.cs file. (Burrowed from @Benito Bertoli)

Answer (score 0):

just clean your project...
I also gone through similar problem..
after clean project everything will be fine..best luck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an image view in your .xml file and a button which dynamically generated and given an id in your java code and these two randomly get a same id and because of that you get this error.
try to change the id which you have given in your code and it will be fine.