# Weird ClassCastException: ImageView cannot be cast to ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Weird ClassCastException: ImageView cannot be cast to ListView.
In xml the view is declared as ListView. When I retrieve the object as follows:

```
private void initShareContextMenu() {
    ListView shareListITem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.share_list);
    shareList = new ContextMenuList(shareListITem,
            (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_wrapper), this);

    List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    views.add(findViewById(R.id.share_btn));

    shareList.setViews(views);
}
```

I got ClassCastException. Tried to build and clean project, remove gen/bin folders, renaming the control but nothing helps.
The layout looks as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/share_list"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/share_context_menu_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/share_list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1px"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>


05-01 09:40:45.215: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-01 09:40:46.096: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
05-01 09:40:46.096: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500):  at com.packagename.ui.activities.VideoPlayerActivity.initShareContextMenu(VideoPlayerActivity.java:1394)
05-01 09:40:46.096: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500):  at com.packagename.ui.activities.VideoPlayerActivity.showVideoEndScreen(VideoPlayerActivity.java:1375)
05-01 09:40:46.096: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500):  at com.packagename.ui.activities.VideoPlayerActivity.onBackPressed(VideoPlayerActivity.java:1587)
05-01 09:40:46.096: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2193)
05-01 09:40:46.096: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)
05-01 09:40:46.096: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2423)
05-01 09:40:46.096: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18500):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1962)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace from logcat.

Comment: @Karakuri added stacktrace

Comment: Can you show us `VideoPlayerActivity.initShareContextMenu`?

Comment: @Karakuri no need, it starts from retrieving the ListView. The line I posted above

Comment: Well clearly something is wrong, and showing that line of code by itself is not enough information to figure that out.

Comment: have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: You need to post you code for 'com.packagename.ui.activities.VideoPlayerActivity.initShareContextMenu(VideoPlayerActivity.java:139`  There is a need for that.

Comment: What is ContextMenuList? Can you post the code for that? What arguments does it take?

Comment: @timusus it's my custom class. Is it necessary? the exception raises on the first line of the initShareContextMenu() method, so the problem is definitely there.

Comment: I have no idea, but I don't have much else to go on.

Comment: Also, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191040/android-java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-imageview-cannot-be-cast-t

Comment: @timusus thanks for your help. I checked this question as well before posting the question, unfortunately it's not my case:(

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to a similar question here:

[Android: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.imageView cannot be cast to android.widget.textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191040/android-java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-imageview-cannot-be-cast-t)

> Eclipse tends to mess up your resources every now and then. This leads
>   to some odd behavior such as strings and images being swapped all over
>   your app, and more commonly classCastException(s), which happen when
>   Eclipse switches your Views' ids around.
>
> A few solutions to that problem:
>
> Clean your project.
>
> Modify an xml layout file and save.
>
> Delete your R file. (Don't worry it will be automatically generated
>   again).
>
> Basically anything that makes your project rebuild and re-generate the
>   R file.